# Edit - Selecting an image on Instagram is not working on my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

> **EDIT #2**

I've just tried selecting every `div` element on the website as each image is contained in a `div`. So, I used `querySelectorAll` followed with an `if` statement. The `if` statement checks the `div` and makes sure the image (class: `FFVAD`) is actually inside of the `div` before proceeding. But it's not working, it's now throwing a `getElementsByClassName is not a function` error.

**My content script:**

```
console.log('injected')
window.onload = function() {
    var imagediv = document.querySelectorAll('div')
    console.log('selected elements')
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imagediv.length; i++) {
        imagediv[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(el){
            if (el.getElementsByClassName('FFVAD').length > 0) { //if the image with the class FFVAD is in the div
                el.target.style.border = "7px solid red" //change the certain div's color
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> PREVIOUS QUESTION

I am developing a chrome extension which injects a javascript-written script into Instagram. I am trying to get the src of each image displayed on the users profile.

I have tried using `document.querySelectorAll('img')` to get every image element, but that isn't working. So, I took a peek in the developer console and noticed each image has a class called `FFVAD`. So, I used `document.getElementsByClassName('FFVAD')` ([reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTNzr.jpg)). I also noticed each image has a `div` element as their parent. So, I tried doing this with my code:

**My content script:**

```
console.log('injected')
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('FFVAD') // instagram sets all 
their images as the class FFVAD, as I looked in the inspect element window
console.log('selected elements')
while(image.length > 0){ //for every image
    image[0].parentNode.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) { //when the image's parent is hovered
        event.style.border = "2px solid red";
    });
    image[0].parentNode.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) { //when the image's parent isn't hovered
        event.style.border = "none";
        });
    image[0].parentNode.addEventListener("click", function(event){ //when the image's parent is clicked
        var child = event.childNodes; //get the image in the image's div
        console.log(child[1].src) //log the src of the image
    });
}
```

**My exensions manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Testing",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "tester123",
  "icons":{
      "16": "icon.png",
      "48": "icon2.png",
      "128": "icon3.png" 
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": ["imgselect.js"],
      "matches": [ "https://*.instagram.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs"
  ]
}
```

I used `parentNode` to get the parent of the image. I expect to see a red border around the image's div parent when it's hovered and seeing the src of the image in the console but I'm not seeing results. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is it giving you any errors?

Comment: @CharlieFish It's not giving me any errors

Comment: Try add the event listener in this way `image[0].addEventListener` and then change `event.style.border = "2px solid red";` into `event.target.style.border = "2px solid red";` And you should do a for loop to change all the element on the image object. Something like `(for i=0; i<image.length; i++)` `image[i].addEventListener`

Comment: @Mattia I just updated my question with new code that I've tried.

Comment: @johnboy13 https://jsfiddle.net/2L9cmyto/13/

Comment: @Mattia thank you for the reply, but it's not working on the actual instagram website. I updated my question again with what I'm trying now. I'm getting an error this time, and it says `getElementByClassName` is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me! 
I looked deeper into the developer console and realized every image on Instagram is inside of multiple divs, so I put together this code that highlights the main div that contains the image, and it works perfectly!

```
console.log('injected')
function show(e) {
    console.log("post found")
    var img = this.getElementsByTagName('img')
    for (i = 0; i <img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].className == "FFVAD"){
            console.log(img[i].src)
            this.style.border = "5px solid red"
        }
    }
}
function hide(e){
    var img = this.getElementsByTagName('img')
    for (i = 0; i <img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].className == "FFVAD"){
            console.log(img[i].src)
            this.style.border = "none"
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function(){
    var imagediv = document.getElementsByClassName('KL4Bh')
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imagediv.length; i++) {
        var parent = imagediv[i].parentNode
        var secondparent = parent.parentNode
        var thirdparent = secondparent.parentNode
        var children = parent.children
        if (children.length > 1){
            children[1].remove()
            thirdparent.addEventListener('mouseover', show)
            thirdparent.addEventListener('mouseout', hide)
        }
    }
},1000)
```